# Previous Marker also gets showed up if I change the location second time

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, android-maps

I am currently showing `marker` on my `current location` whenever the current location gets changed. And the below code works fine. But the problem with this is,- Suppose for the first time I passed some location and my marker will be there at that position but the second time if I pass any other different location then my marker will be there in second location but at the same time my marker also stays in First Location too and I don't want this thing. I only need whenever the Current Location changes all other marker should gets disappeared, only the current location marker should be there. Hope I am clear to everyone

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

    }

    public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

            Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
            int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
            marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);


            myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);


            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);

            myItemizedOverlay.addItem(point, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
            mapController.animateTo(point);
            String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mapView.invalidate();

        }
}
```

Below is my ItemizedOverlay class-

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        populate();
    }

    public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String title, String snippet){
        OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(p, title, snippet);
        overlayItemList.add(newItem);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return overlayItemList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return overlayItemList.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        overlayItemList.clear();
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        //boundCenterBottom(marker);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to remove previously added items before adding the new one

```
public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String title, String snippet){
    OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(p, title, snippet);
    overlayItemList.removeAll();
    overlayItemList.add(newItem);
    populate();
}
```